# C++ assign a pointed-to array to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I got the following problem: I want to assign a value which is pointed at to another value. How I do this? I tried it this way:

```
trialstr(0,0) = *stress(0);
```

But this did not work. I received this error message:

‘stress’ cannot be used as a function

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Parentheses are used for functions. To access elements of an array you are looking at square brackets (`[]`). Also, we need more code to be able to help you.

Comment: Please show the relevant declarations. What is `stress`? What is `trialstr`?

Comment: You might also want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The declaratons are the following: LINBOX::Matrix<3,3> trialstr and LINBOX::Matrix<6,1> *stress, Pileborg thank you for the advice. Iwill keep that in mind for my next posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the function-call operation has higher precedence than the indirection (dereference) operator, which means that from the compiler point of view you are doing

```
*(stress(0))
```

in other words you try to dereference what `stress(0)` returns.

What you want (I assume) is to first dereference the `stress` pointer an then use the function call operator `()` on the dereferenced pointer:

```
(*stress)(0)
```

Comment: Pileborg that was exactly what I need. Thank you!